# Could someone explain the word recursive in relation to computers/programming? I Am having a difficult time understanding its use

Tags: registry, vocabulary

In my computing course, the word recursively is used quite a bit - I'm trying to have a deeper understanding of its use and was wondering if someone could enlighten me.

EX: Searches HKLM recursively for the Key SAM

Answer (score 2):

[@vekerdyb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59900941/3439404) is right: *recursively **in search terms** usually means to search **in each (sub)level***. Of course, [recursion (in computer science)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) is a bit more universal (more general) concept (see also  [@Maffe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59899679/3439404)).

Taking your example as a task request *"search HKLM recursively for the key SAM"* then a solution in Windows `cmd` *could* stem from [`reg.exe` utility](https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html), see also (truncated) excerpt from `reg query /?` help:

> ```
> REG QUERY KeyName [/v [ValueName] | /ve] [/s]
>           [/f Data [/k] [/d] [/c] [/e]] [/t Type] [/z] [/se Separator]
>           [/reg:32 | /reg:64]
>
>   /s       Queries all subkeys and values recursively (like dir /s).
>
>   /f       Specifies the data or pattern to search for.
>            Use double quotes if a string contains spaces. Default is "*".
>
>   /k       Specifies to search in key names only.
>
>   /c       Specifies that the search is case sensitive.
>            The default search is case insensitive.
>
>   /e       Specifies to return only exact matches.
>            By default all the matches are returned.
> ```

For explanation of `/s` switch *…**recursively** (like `dir /s`)* see `dir /? | find /I " /s"`

```
/S    Displays files in specified directory and all subdirectories.
```

---

Now, you can see the difference: *search HKLM for the key SAM* (**not recursively**)

```
reg query HKLM /K /C /E /F SAM
```

> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM
> End of search: 1 match(es) found.
> ```

versus *search HKLM **recursively** for the key SAM*:

```
reg query HKLM /K /C /E /F SAM /S
```

> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY\SAM
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Audit\SystemPolicy\ObjectAccess\SAM
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\SAM
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\EventLog\System\SAM
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SAM
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\System\SAM
> End of search: 8 match(es) found.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

"The best way to understand recursion is understand recursion."

Generally speaking, recursion happens when you use something to explain itself.

In computer programming, recursion happens when you call a function/method from itself. For example, this function:

```
    function printHello() {

        print("Hello!")   //this prints "Hello!" on the console
        printHello()      //this starts from the beginning
    }
```

will run endlessly printing "Hello!" infinite time.

Recursion can be useful in different situations, for example to computate the factorial of a number.

In maths, the factorial of n is the product (n)*(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3)*...

In programming, we can computate the factorial of a number n with a recursive function, in this way:

```
//recursive
var factorial = function(n) {
    if(n == 0) {
        return 1
    } else {
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
    }
}

console.log(factorial(num));
```

Answer (score 0):

@Maffe's answer is correct, but to expand to your example, "recursively" in search terms usually means to search in each level.

(I don't know what `HKLM` `Key SAM` are in the context of your example so instead I will use a simple file-system search.)

If your working directory is `/home/user1` and you search (non-recursively) for the file `test.txt`, it means that you are searching for files called `/home/user1/test.txt`.
If you are searching recursively, it means that you search the current directory `/home/user1`, and any subdirectories (like `/home/user1/documents`), and any subdirectories of subdirectories (like `/home/user1/documents/tests`), etc.

In pseudo code:

```
define searchRecursively(path, filename):
  results := []
  for every file in path:
    if file.name is filename:
      add file to the list of results
    if file.type is directory:
      subresults := searchRecursively(file, filename) # this is why it is recursive
      add all elements of subresults to results
  return results
```